# STB Loading png to OpenGl Texture results in black or white backgroud

Tags: c++, opengl

Hello I've got weird problem with my code, i've been looking for some time on stack and found no answer, there was few similar problems, but they didn't solve anything.

```
int createTexture(const char* path) {
    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    int colorMode = nrChannels == 3 ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA;
    if (data) {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, colorMode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);
    return texture;
}
```

Here i have function loading texture, I choose GL_RGB or GL_RGBA depending on number of channels. I've good results of 3 and 4 channels depending on jpg/png image i use. Anyways i have white background, ( it was black before i edited it in GIMP )

```
// set the texture wrapping/filtering options (on currently bound texture)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    

// load and create a texture 
    // -------------------------
    unsigned int texture1 = createTexture("brick.jpg");
    unsigned int texture2 = createTexture("grafiti.png");

    // Mode

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    // Shader Class

    Shader currentShader("vertexShader.glsl", "fragmentShader.glsl");

    currentShader.use();
    currentShader.setInt("texture1", 0);
    currentShader.setInt("texture2", 1);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        processInput(window);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
        currentShader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices) / sizeof(int), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

Then I use this textures together with this shaders

Fragment

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;

void main()
{
    FragColor = mix(texture(texture1, TexCoord), texture(texture2, TexCoord), 1);
}
```

Vertex

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}

float vertices[] = {
        // positions // colors // texture coords
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f // top left
    };

    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3,
    };

    unsigned int VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    unsigned int VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    unsigned int EBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

I'm sorry if my english is hideous but it's middle of the night and i'm struggling with this for hours right now

Comment: Have you checked for any errors with `glGetError`?

Comment: I've done it right now and there is no errors

Comment: Are the vertices laid out correctly? I.e. can you render them with colors instead of the textures? Also, you're aware the using a factor of 1 in your `mix` function will only render one the first texture?

Comment: I've tried rendering one texture and same thing happens. I've configured verticies as there was said in book i've been learning from so it would be weird if they were configured badly.

Comment: I've added verticies configuration to question, just in case

Comment: They seem fine. In that case, you probably have to simplify your problem. Go back to just rendering one texture and make sure that works before you're trying to render multiple. If you can't get that working, go back to render a triangle and work your back way up. Create a new project where you copy everything into so you don't loose anything. Then you could either start from scratch and copy in snippets, or start ripping things out.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, enabling blend was not satisfying so i wrote fragmentShader in different way

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;

void main()
{
    vec4 AlphaColor = texture(texture2, TexCoord);
    if(AlphaColor.a < 0.1) {
        FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
    } else {
        FragColor = mix(texture(texture1, TexCoord), AlphaColor, 0.9);
    }
}
```

Right now FragmentShader understands alpha channel and will mix only pixels without alpha